# How to create a list of column names, row names, and values from data frame in panda?

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to python. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
     A   B  
  E  0   1

  F  2   3
```

I want to convert this data frame to a list that looks like this:

```
  [[E, A, 0], [E, B, 1], [F, A, 2], [F, B, 3]]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [197]: df.stack().reset_index().values.tolist()
Out[197]: [['E', 'A', 0L], ['E', 'B', 1L], ['F', 'A', 2L], ['F', 'B', 3L]]
```

Comment: You win for 3s :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
df.reset_index().melt('index').values.tolist()
Out[1423]: [['E', 'A', 0], ['F', 'A', 2], ['E', 'B', 1], ['F', 'B', 3]]
```

Comment: @BahadorSaket Go ahead :-)